# Efficient page numbering of PDF FPDI

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I have a php script that numbers the pages of an existing PDF. But it for example does not work with a PDF file that is 100MB.

What should i edit in the code so files that are big (100mb+) also will be numbered? Or is that not possible?

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
// or for usage with TCPDF:
// use setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi;

// or for usage with tFPDF:
// use setasign\Fpdi\Tfpdf\Fpdi;

// setup the autoload function
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$fileName = $_FILES["pdf"]["name"];

$pdfFile = $_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"];


// configure page numbering for pages
class PDF extends FPDI
{
    function Footer()
    {
        // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Select Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
        // Print centered page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '.$this->PageNo().' van {nb}',0,0,'R');
    }
}

// generate a new pdf that includes the page numbering
// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

// set the source file
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($pdfFile);

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);


    // import page 1
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);


}

$pdf->Output();


?>
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a good description of the problem you encounter. Have you analyzed what the exact problem is? Memory? Processing time? A bug?

Comment: You are right. The error I was getting when posting the 100MB PDF was that the POST content length was not high enough. Therefore I changed the following two settings in the php.ini to: post_max_size = 4000mb and upload_max_filesize= 4000MB. The next error I was getting is: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67251120 bytes) in C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\pdfpagenumbering\vendor\setasign\fpdi\src\Fpdi.php on line 150

There are also PDF files that are atleast 2 GBs of size

Comment: You will not be able to handle this with FPDI, because it assembles the new PDF in memory. What you need is a script that is able to modify an existing document without reading the document completely into memory. You also should not do such hugh tasks in realtime but you should work with a queue and your should procees a specific page count per run. We have a non-free solution (The [SetaPDF-Stamper](https://setasign.com/stamper) component) which may help you with this. If you want to I can prepare a simple example as an answer.